# Is there a command like pstree for libraries?

Tags: linux, rhel5

I need to determine whether a library named `libunaSA.so` is being called directly by the process or by another library called `libtoki2.so`. I guess what I'm looking for is a pstree for libraries. The system is running RHEL 5.3 Beta.

This output shows the two libraries in the process map

```
# grep -e toki -e una /proc/2335/maps
0043f000-004ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 543465     /usr/lib/libtoki2.so
004ad000-004c5000 rwxp 0006d000 08:02 543465     /usr/lib/libtoki2.so
01185000-01397000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 543503     /usr/lib/libunaSA.so
01397000-013dc000 rwxp 00211000 08:02 543503     /usr/lib/libunaSA.so
```

This output shows that only the `libtoki2.so` library is in the current cache

```
# ldconfig -p | grep -e una -e toki
libtoki2.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libtoki2.so
libtoki.so.4.4.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libtoki.so.4.4.1
libtoki.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libtoki.so.2
```

I attached strace to the running process but it doesn't provide much output

```
# strace -p 2335
Process 2335 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0xb7ef5bd8, FUTEX_WAIT, 2336, NULL
```

Here's the output to ldd for each library

```
# ldd /usr/lib/libtoki2.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00a0a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x001bd000)
        libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 (0x00f3f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00b27000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0043d000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00742000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00110000)
# ldd /usr/lib/libunaSA.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00244000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00baf000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x007fa000)
        libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 (0x009ce000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00c96000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x004a2000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00742000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00a9f000)
```

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but you might be able to infer some part of your answer by starting you process with strace instead of attaching to it once it's already running...

Comment: You could also try using ltrace instead of strace: both are usable in the exact same situations, but strace tracks calls and ltrace tracks library usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you posted suggests that libunaSA.so stands alone. libtoki2.so does not require libunaSA (as shown by ldd). You could try using ltrace or lsof against the running application to see if libunaSA is called; if libtoki2 makes the call, then it will be hidden (I believe) from the output of ltrace.

lsof will show if the binary requires libunaSA at all.

Both ltrace and lsof are available for RHEL 5.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to ltrace. I have opened another question to get it to run in tomcat. http://serverfault.com/questions/222669

Comment: For reference's sake: running ltrace against a complex system like Tomcat is unlikely to avail much: there are too many things going on, too many new processes working in concert.